# Davening from an electronic device?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, prayer-book, electricity

I have been davening from my ipad using a pdf copy of a siddur I downloaded. However, I wanted to know if this is a suitable alternative for those times when the use of electronic devices is permissible. Does this present any halacha violation?

Comment: I don't have an official ruling on this, but the mass of people who use apps and pdfs to daven from seems to speak to there being no violation on weekdays.

Comment: IMHO davening from electronic devices is fine if you're stuck somewhere without a siddur... but if you're davening in shule with siddurim all around - you should be using a siddur like everyone else

Comment: @Danield Why?  .

Comment: Well, I have seen people daven with iphone/samsung and it seemed like a lot of effort went into scrolling every 2 seconds or so (diverting concentration from davening to device usage)... also what do you gain by using an electronic device over a siddur ? Also, I think this could cause distraction to others (whether this is justified or not, I still think this has to be taken into account)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found [a discussion of possible problems](http://www.haoros.com/Archive/index.asp?kovetz=1022&cat=9&haoro=5), the writer seems not to like the idea, though doesn't rule it out completely.

Issues that are addressed there (my comments in parentheses):

- Holding something valuable during Davenning is prohibited since the possibility of it falling bothers כוונה. (A Siddur is permitted, I woudn't assume a difference since people who are davenning are as careful not to drop a Siddur as a iPad)
- Jumping alerts can interfere. (This seems to be a real problem, my phone can block messages when an app is up, but not phone calls. A device which can shut off everything during davenning, would not have this problem.)
- One should be able to Daven without distractions, including looking for things in a siddur, so he should have page numbers all written down. (Still, a siddur is better than nothing, searching a PDF for הלל wouldn't be different than flipping pages, IMHO. Moreover, Siddur apps give you the relevant davenning only, and in order.)
- While davenning one should hold his hands by his heart (Again, I can't see why an iPad would differ from a Siddur here)

To sum it up, I personally don't see a problem. I would add one should have a regular siddur for use on Shabbat and Chagim, because if he gets used to relying on the iPad he can get stuck on those occasions.